# Необходимо чтобы все меню открывались одинаково

Tags: html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Одно выпадающее меню(первое) открывается по другому,чем остальные, необходимо чтобы оно открывалось так же как и все

```js
function showMenu1() {
  $('.menu_dropdown1').slideDown(300);
  $('.menu_dropdown2,.menu_dropdown3,.menu_dropdown4').slideUp(300);
}
$(document).ready(function() {



  $(".menu_element1").on("mouseover", showMenu1);
   $("#dr1").on("mouseover", showMenu1);
   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
     var container = $('.menu_dropdown1');
     if(e.target != container[0] && !container.has(e.target).length) {
         container.slideUp("fast");
     }
 });

    $(".menu_element2").on("mouseover", showMenu2);
   $("#dr2").on("mouseover", showMenu2);
   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
     var container = $('.menu_dropdown2');
     if(e.target != container[0] && !container.has(e.target).length) {
         container.slideUp("fast");
     }
 });

    $(".menu_element3").on("mouseover", showMenu3);
   $("#dr3").on("mouseover", showMenu3);
   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
     var container = $('.menu_dropdown3');
     if(e.target != container[0] && !container.has(e.target).length) {
         container.slideUp("fast");
     }
 });

    $(".menu_element4").on("mouseover", showMenu4);
   $("#dr4").on("mouseover", showMenu4);
   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
     var container = $('.menu_dropdown4');
     if(e.target != container[0] && !container.has(e.target).length) {
         container.slideUp("fast");
     }
 });
});



function showMenu2() {
  $('.menu_dropdown2').slideDown(700);
  $('.menu_dropdown1,.menu_dropdown3,.menu_dropdown4').slideUp(300);
}


function showMenu3() {
  $('.menu_dropdown3').slideDown(700);
  $('.menu_dropdown2,.menu_dropdown1,.menu_dropdown4').slideUp(300);
}


function showMenu4() {
  $('.menu_dropdown4').slideDown(700);
  $('.menu_dropdown2,.menu_dropdown3,.menu_dropdown1').slideUp(300);
}
```

```css
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 
}
body{
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 background-color:#DCD8CF;
}
.header{
 display: flex;

 background-color: #282827;
 height: 100px;
 width: 1600px;
}
.menu_list{
 margin-top: 0px;
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: 0px;
}
.menu_element1,.menu_element2,.menu_element3,.menu_element4{
 justify-content: center;
 align-items:   center;
 display: flex;
 width: 140px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-left: 100px;
 border-left: 3px solid #E25D33;
 border-right: 3px solid #E25D33;
}
.menu_element1:hover,.menu_element2:hover,.menu_element3:hover,.menu_element4:hover{
 border-left: 3px solid #E25D33;
 border-right: 3px solid #E25D33;
 background-color: #E25D33;
 color: #282827;
 transition: 0.4s;
 position: relative;
}
#menu_element1:hover,#menu_element2:hover,#menu_element3:hover,#menu_element4:hover a{
 color: #282827;
 transition: 0.4s;
}

.logo{
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 
}

.icon-phonegap-seeklogocom, .logo{
 font-size: 50px;
 height: 20px;
 color: #E25D33;
 width: 20px;
}
/*DROPED MENU*/

.menu_element1,.menu_element2,.menu_element3,.menu_element4 {
 width: 200px;
 position: relative;
}

.menu_dropdown1,.menu_dropdown2,.menu_dropdown3,.menu_dropdown4 {
 display: none; 
 width: 300px;
 position: absolute;
 /*margin-top: 60px;*/
 border-bottom: 2px solid gold;
 border-top: 2px solid gold;
 border-left: 2px solid #ADA2F6;
 border-right: 2px solid #ADA2F6;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 
}



#dr1,#dr2,#dr3,#dr4 {
 color: #E25D33;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 5px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 width: 60px;
 text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
   <ul class="menu_list">
    <li class="menu_element1" ><a id="dr1"  href="">Winter</a></li><div class="menu_dropdown1">
        <p>Games</p>
        <p>Programs</p>
        <p>Soft</p>
        <p>Sale</p>
      </div>
    <li class="menu_element2"><a id="dr2" href="">Spring</a><div class="menu_dropdown2">
        <p>Games</p>
        <p>Programs</p>
        <p>Soft</p>
        <p>Sale</p>
      </div></li>
    <li class="menu_element3" ><a id="dr3"  href="">Summer</a><div class="menu_dropdown3">
        <p>Games</p>
        <p>Programs</p>
        <p>Soft</p>
        <p>Sale</p>
      </div></li>
    <li  class="menu_element4"><a id="dr4" href="">Autumn</a><div class="menu_dropdown4">
        <p>Games</p>
        <p>Programs</p>
        <p>Soft</p>
        <p>Sale</p>
      </div></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас самый первый дропдаун находится не в элементе списка, а все остальные находятся в таких элементах. Отсюда разное поведение

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".menu_element1").on("mouseover", showMenu1);
   $("#dr1").on("mouseover", showMenu1);
   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
     var container = $('.menu_dropdown1');
     if(e.target != container[0] && !container.has(e.target).length) {
         container.slideUp("fast");
     }
 });

 $(".menu_element2").on("mouseover", showMenu2);
   $("#dr2").on("mouseover", showMenu2);
   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
     var container = $('.menu_dropdown2');
     if(e.target != container[0] && !container.has(e.target).length) {
         container.slideUp("fast");
     }
 });

 $(".menu_element3").on("mouseover", showMenu3);
   $("#dr3").on("mouseover", showMenu3);
   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
     var container = $('.menu_dropdown3');
     if(e.target != container[0] && !container.has(e.target).length) {
         container.slideUp("fast");
     }
 });

 $(".menu_element4").on("mouseover", showMenu4);
   $("#dr4").on("mouseover", showMenu4);
   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
     var container = $('.menu_dropdown4');
     if(e.target != container[0] && !container.has(e.target).length) {
         container.slideUp("fast");
     }
 });
});

function showMenu1() {
  $('.menu_dropdown1').slideDown(700);
  $('.menu_dropdown2,.menu_dropdown3,.menu_dropdown4').slideUp(300);
}

function showMenu2() {
  $('.menu_dropdown2').slideDown(700);
  $('.menu_dropdown1,.menu_dropdown3,.menu_dropdown4').slideUp(300);
}

function showMenu3() {
  $('.menu_dropdown3').slideDown(700);
  $('.menu_dropdown2,.menu_dropdown1,.menu_dropdown4').slideUp(300);
}

function showMenu4() {
  $('.menu_dropdown4').slideDown(700);
  $('.menu_dropdown2,.menu_dropdown3,.menu_dropdown1').slideUp(300);
}
```

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 background-color:#DCD8CF;
}

.header {
 display: flex;

 background-color: #282827;
 height: 100px;
 width: 1600px;
}

.menu_list {
 margin-top: 0px;
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.menu_element1,.menu_element2,.menu_element3,.menu_element4 {
 justify-content: center;
 align-items:   center;
 display: flex;
 width: 140px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-left: 100px;
 border-left: 3px solid #E25D33;
 border-right: 3px solid #E25D33;
}

.menu_element1:hover,.menu_element2:hover,.menu_element3:hover,.menu_element4:hover {
 border-left: 3px solid #E25D33;
 border-right: 3px solid #E25D33;
 background-color: #E25D33;
 color: #282827;
 transition: 0.4s;
 position: relative;
}

#menu_element1:hover,#menu_element2:hover,#menu_element3:hover,#menu_element4:hover a {
 color: #282827;
 transition: 0.4s;
}

.logo {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 80px;
}

.icon-phonegap-seeklogocom, .logo {
 font-size: 50px;
 height: 20px;
 color: #E25D33;
 width: 20px;
}

/*DROPED MENU*/
.menu_element1,.menu_element2,.menu_element3,.menu_element4 {
 width: 200px;
 position: relative;
}

.menu_dropdown1,.menu_dropdown2,.menu_dropdown3,.menu_dropdown4 {
 display: none; 
 width: 300px;
 position: absolute;
 /*margin-top: 60px;*/
 border-bottom: 2px solid gold;
 border-top: 2px solid gold;
 border-left: 2px solid #ADA2F6;
 border-right: 2px solid #ADA2F6;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

#dr1,#dr2,#dr3,#dr4 {
 color: #E25D33;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 5px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 width: 60px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
   <ul class="menu_list">
    <li class="menu_element1" ><a id="dr1"  href="">Winter</a>
        <div class="menu_dropdown1">
        <p>Games</p>
        <p>Programs</p>
        <p>Soft</p>
        <p>Sale</p>
    </div></li>
    <li class="menu_element2"><a id="dr2" href="">Spring</a>
        <div class="menu_dropdown2">
        <p>Games</p>
        <p>Programs</p>
        <p>Soft</p>
        <p>Sale</p>
     </div></li>
    <li class="menu_element3" ><a id="dr3"  href="">Summer</a><div class="menu_dropdown3">
        <p>Games</p>
        <p>Programs</p>
        <p>Soft</p>
        <p>Sale</p>
      </div></li>
    <li  class="menu_element4"><a id="dr4" href="">Autumn</a><div class="menu_dropdown4">
        <p>Games</p>
        <p>Programs</p>
        <p>Soft</p>
        <p>Sale</p>
      </div></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Но, честно говоря, код так и просит рефакторинга. Давайте попробуем его улучшить
Что сделаем:

1. У вас очень много дублирующих селекторов (`menu_element1, menu_elementN`). Они не нужны и только мешают читать код. А так как логика и стили для них одинаковые, от них можно избавиться
2. Можно скрывать не все дропдауны, кроме того, что нужно показать, а скрывать только тот дропдаун, который сейчас показывается. Это можно сделать, просто добавив ему какой-то класс (`menu_dropdown_active`);

Даже эти два пункта уже уменьшают код в несколько раз

```js
function showMenu() {
  const $dropDown = $(this).find('.menu_dropdown');
  const $activeDropDown = $('.menu_dropdown_active');
  if ($dropDown.hasClass('menu_dropdown_active')) {
    return;
  }

  // Hide active dropdown.
  hideMenu($activeDropDown);

  // Show new dropdown.
  $dropDown.slideDown(300);
  $dropDown.addClass('menu_dropdown_active');
}

function hideMenu($menu) {
  $menu.slideUp(300);
  $menu.removeClass('menu_dropdown_active');
}

$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".menu_element").on("mouseover", showMenu);

  $(document).mouseup((e) => {
    const $container = $('.menu_dropdown_active');
    if(e.target != $container[0] && !$container.has(e.target).length) {
      hideMenu($container);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background-color:#DCD8CF;
}

.header {
  display: flex;

  background-color: #282827;
  height: 100px;
  width: 1600px;
}

.menu_list {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.menu_element {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:   center;
  display: flex;
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  border-left: 3px solid #E25D33;
  border-right: 3px solid #E25D33;
}

.menu_element1:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #E25D33;
  border-right: 3px solid #E25D33;
  background-color: #E25D33;
  color: #282827;
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: relative;
}


/*DROPED MENU*/
.menu_element {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu_dropdown {
  display: none; 
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gold;
  border-top: 2px solid gold;
  border-left: 2px solid #ADA2F6;
  border-right: 2px solid #ADA2F6;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#dr1, #dr2, #dr3, #dr4 {
  color: #E25D33;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="menu_list">
      <li class="menu_element" >
        <a id="dr1" href="">Winter</a>
        <div class="menu_dropdown">
          <p>Games</p>
          <p>Programs</p>
          <p>Soft</p>
          <p>Sale</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="menu_element">
        <a id="dr2" href="">Spring</a>
        <div class="menu_dropdown">
          <p>Games</p>
          <p>Programs</p>
          <p>Soft</p>
          <p>Sale</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="menu_element" >
        <a id="dr3" href="">Summer</a>
        <div class="menu_dropdown">
          <p>Games</p>
          <p>Programs</p>
          <p>Soft</p>
          <p>Sale</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="menu_element">
        <a id="dr4" href="">Autumn</a>
        <div class="menu_dropdown">
          <p>Games</p>
          <p>Programs</p>
          <p>Soft</p>
          <p>Sale</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```